# How do I move a file from the Downloads folder into the opt folder on Ubuntu?

Tags: vmware, ns2, opt

I am trying to install a network simulator onto Ubuntu on my virtual machine(VMWare). It requires me to move the file downloaded into the opt folder in order for me to run other commands for installation. Tried this: `sudo cp -r /home/denisayebare/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz/opt/`

And brought back this:

```
cp: missing destination file operand after '/home/denisayebare/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz/opt/
```

Comment: Try `sudo cp /home/denisayebare/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz /opt`, `-r` switch is not needed if you intend to copy only 1 file.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo cp -r /home/denisayebare/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz/opt/
```

is missing a space. It needs to be ...

```
sudo cp /home/denisayebare/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz /opt/
```

The `-r` is only for recursive copying so omit it when copying just files and no directories.

Comment: Thank you @Rinzwind